# Photoshop Undo Behavior - Undo between last state and current state

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So, I'm pretty sure that the default Undo behavior before on Photoshop would be that it would only undo to the last action if you pressed Ctrl+Z and that if you pressed it again it would actually redo your last action and go back to your previous state.

Nowadays it seems that if you keep pressing Ctrl+Z it just keeps undoing your actions indefinitely which is a really annoying behavior as I quickly want to preview the last change I made and compare it to the previous state quickly.

Am I dreaming or this used to be the default behavior before?

Does anyone know if there's a setting to switch between these behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it changed recently, CC2018 or 2019, not certain which.

To revert the behaviour...

Prefs > Keyboard Shortcuts > Use Legacy Undo Shortcuts

[image]

It takes a week or two to overcome muscle memory, but I now actually prefer the new method [which is actually a much older method brought back again]